# Where do I find the commandname handler for asp:linkbutton

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Trying to debug a aspx script.  Don't know any asp.net.

I've come across this piece of code:

```
<asp:LinkButton
    ID="EditButton"
    runat="server"
    CausesValidation="False"
    CommandName="Edit"
    Text="Edit"
    CssClass="LightBlue">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

From this site:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.command%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
```

I see that the method to look for is `LinkButton_Command`.  I have done a search in all the files and not found this method.

This link is doing something, so it's not ignored.  Could this method have a different name and if so how do I find what it is?

I have changed the `Text` attribute and that change is there when I run it, so I have the right piece of code.

I've also changed the `CommandName` attribute and the link stops working, so something somewhere is handling it.

There are two more linkbuttons in the code immediately after it:

```
<asp:LinkButton
    ID="DeleteButton"
    runat="server"
    CausesValidation="False"
    CommandName="Delete"
    Text="Delete"
    CssClass="LightBlue"
    OnClick="DeleteButton_Click">
</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:LinkButton
    ID="NewButton"
    runat="server"
    CausesValidation="False"
    CommandName="New"
    Text="New"
    CssClass="LightBlue">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I notice that the deletebutton has an onclick attribute, and I can find that method within the same script, but nothing obvious near that handler for the other two.

EDIT:

Another way of getting the answer that I want might be to ask the question:

What are all the different ways to add a click handler to a asp:linkbutton?

EDIT:

Don't know if it helps, but the link button is inside the following structure:

```
<ajax:UpdatePanel...>
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:FormView
     id="FormView1"
     runat="server"
     OnItemDeleted="FormView1_ItemDeleted"
     DataKeyNames="Id"
     OnDataBound="FormView1_DataBound"
     OnItemUpdated="FormView1_ItemUpdated"
     OnItemUpdating="FormView1_ItemUpdating"
     OnItemInserted="FormView1_ItemInserted"
     OnItemInserting="FormView1_ItemInserting"
     DefaultMode="Insert"
     DataSourceID="odsLogEntryForm"
     >
      <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton"...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference with the example from the site you posted is that they used the OnCommand="LinkButton_Command" to subscribe the handler to the event. In your example this is not the case. This can mean 2 things:
- The event is not handled
- The event is subscribed to in code, probably in the code behind file of the aspx/ascx file (.aspx.cs). Look for the following code:

```
EditButton.Command += <name of the function to handle the command event>;
```

- EditButton is the name of your LinkButton.
- Command is the name of the event to handle.
- <name of the function to handle the command event> is a function which the programmer created. He/She could have named it anything.

---

After seeing your edit:

The event is handled by the encapsulating FormView. A FormView will handle command events of a inner buttons. Since the CommandName of the LinkButtons is set to "Delete" and "New" is will be handled by the corresponding events in the FormView.

see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview_events(v=vs.110).aspx for the available events of a FormVIew in this case the events with the name "Item" apply.

Comment: is there a default code behind page.  The page with the editbutton has `MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"` and that page has no code behind declaration.  Also I have done a global search for `editbutton` and nothing useful found